# Why can't I access hosts using command prompt?

Tags: cmd

According to Wikipedia, the path to hosts is:

```
C:\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

However, when I tried to access the file, this error came up:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: `C:\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Only use backslashes in paths. Only admins can edit this file.

Answer (score 1):

The `hosts` file is within your Windows folder: `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\drivers\etc`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons why I do not trust Wikipedia with information involving syntax. Because if you notice the line that you posted the slash after the colon is incorrect (**C:/**). The correct way is like this: **(C:\)**. 
And also you are supposed to put START before the file so it will run. The file path is also incorrect.

The proper syntax is:

```
start C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

You may also need admin privileges to run this file.

Comment: The start is unnecessary. See `start /?` for an explanation of starting files with and without the `start` command. As the file is extensionless you need to specify an action in full so `notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: When I enter the path into cmd without start it gives me the error up above. Without start the file wouldn't even know to open.

Comment: If you wanted to be specific about which application runs with the file you can type notepad and then the path, but if you want options you type start and then the path. The person asking did not give a specific application he/she wanted to open it with.

Comment: With `start` it doesn't start either because there are no filetype registered for extensionless file as standard in Windows.

Comment: It worked for me. When I pressed enter it brought up options it can open the file with, and I opened up notepad through there.